# Angular getting BehaviorSubject value error: Property 'access_token' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular project I have authentication methods in the auth.service
I am storing the admin access token I got from the API in a BehaviorSubject

```
adminData = new BehaviorSubject(null);

saveAdminData(token:any) {
    let admin:any = new AdminData(token);
    this.adminData.next(admin);
}
```

There is a function that I need to access the access_token of the admin so I tried this

```
this.adminData.value.access_token;
```

But it gives me this error `Object is possibly 'null'` so I tried this

```
this.adminData.value!.access_token;
```

But I have different error `Property 'access_token' does not exist on type 'never'.`

Comment: do like this `adminData = new BehaviorSubject<any | null>(null);` and you can replace any with your own model

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the `BehaviorSubject`. You have to tell typescript the type of object you are trying to implement, try this:

```js
adminData = new BehaviorSubject<any | null>(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ReplaySubject which behaves like a BehaviorSubject, but you don't need an initial value.

```
adminData = new ReplaySubject<any | null>();
```